# showing the vector form of the solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

[Example of a matrix form of a system of linear equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Par6Q.png)
I am studying for linear algebra exam and there is one part I do not understand in this example. Why is the vector form of the solution: $$sx_1 + tx_2$$ please help me understand.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Notice that what is written is actually not $sx_1+tx_2$, it is $s\chi_1+t\chi_2$ (notice the difference in handwriting).